# Authenticate With Workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-notebooks

I have a Pipeline registered in my AML workspace. Now I would like to trigger a pipeline run from an Azure Notebook in the same Workspace.
In order to get a reference object to the workspace in the notebook I need to authenticate, e.g.

`ws = Workspace.from_config()`

However, InteractiveLoginAthentication is blocked by my company's domain and MsiAuthentication throws an error as well. ServicePrincipalAuthentication works, but how do I keep the secret safe? What is the prefered way of dealing with secrets in the Azure Machine Learning Service Notebooks?